# Старт анимации JavaScript с задержкой выполнения

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в этом коде правильно прописать, чтобы начало второй и третьей анимации начиналось не одновременно с первой, а спустя 2 и 4 секунды соответственно?

```
    $('.panel').animate({
    top:0,
    opacity:1
}, 1000);

$('.panel2').animate({
    top:50,
    opacity:1,  
}, 3000);

$('.panel3').animate({
    top:100,
    opacity:1
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй так)

```
$('.panel').animate({
    top:0,
    opacity:1
}, 1000);

$('.panel2').delay(2000).animate({
    top:50,
    opacity:1,  
}, 3000);

$('.panel3').delay(6000).animate({
    top:100,
    opacity:1
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо) уже разобрался) лепил до этого delay после animate, а не до))